# AndEngine GLES2-AnchorCenter Custom font on API 21 don't work

Tags: java, android, andengine, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm using AndEngine GLES2-AnchorCenter, I want to create Text with custom font.

My Code:

```
BitmapTextureAtlas bookos25Texture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(textureManager, 256, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
bookosFont25 = FontFactory.createStrokeFromAsset(activity.getFontManager(), bookos25Texture, activity.getAssets(), "font/MarkerFelt.ttc",25, true,  Color.WHITE.getARGBPackedInt(), 1, brown.getARGBPackedInt());
bookosFont25.load();
```

Result on API 21

[image: API 21]

Result on API 16

[image: API 16]

So it's only happend to me or it's common issue and AndEngine don't support API 21 at this moment? Maybe I'm doing it in some not quite good way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. The problem in my case was the format of the font. I was using .ttf format and it was not showing properly (like the one you have in your first picture). To fix this I converted it to .otf. Maybe this will fix your problem as well.

Comment: Yes, that was my issue. I solve it while ago, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Font aFont = FontFactory.createFromAsset(activity.getFontManager(), activity.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR, activity.getAssets(), fontName, fontSize, true, Color.WHITE)

aFont.load();
```

works for me with API 21.